# how to add the objects to Static List for below program to increment it

Tags: java

Here in the code below the user interface class gets the input from the user and set it to the bean class and the book service class is initiated and the get tickets method is called and the booking id is set according to the booking list:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInterfaceBook {

    static List<BookDetailsBean> Bookinglist = new ArrayList<BookDetailsBean>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter your Name");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Address");


        String address=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter emailid");
        String email=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Event");
        String Event=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter mobilenumber");
        Long mobilenumber=sc.nextLong();




        System.out.println("Enter number of tickets");
        int nooftickets=sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        BookDetailsBean bean=new BookDetailsBean();
        bean.setName(name);
        bean.setAddress(address);
        bean.setEmail(email);
        bean.setMobilenumber(mobilenumber);
        bean.setEvnets(Event);
        bean.setNooftickets(nooftickets);

        BookService bs=new BookService();
        try {


            System.out.println(bs.gettickets(bean));
            UserInterfaceBook.Bookinglist.add(bean);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And booking id is set according to the list and  the object is added to the booking list:

```
public class BookService {
    int bid=0;

    public int gettickets(BookDetailsBean b) throws Exception {

        BookValidator bava=new BookValidator();

        if (bava.IsValidName(b.getName())){

            if (bava.IsValidEmail(b.getEmail())){

               if (bava.IsValidTicket(b.getNooftickets())) {
                  bid=UserInterfaceBook.Bookinglist.size()+1;

                   b.setBookingid(bid);




               }

           }

        }
        return bid;

    }

}
```

Book details got all the variables with setter and getter methods:

````
public class BookDetailsBean {
    private int bookingid;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Long mobilenumber;
    private String address;
    private String evnets;
    private int nooftickets;




    public int getBookingid() {
        return bookingid;
    }
    public void setBookingid(int bookingid) {
        this.bookingid = bookingid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Long getMobilenumber() {
        return mobilenumber;
    }
    public void setMobilenumber(Long mobilenumber) {
        this.mobilenumber = mobilenumber;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getEvnets() {
        return evnets;
    }
    public void setEvnets(String evnets) {
        this.evnets = evnets;
    }
    public int getNooftickets() {
        return nooftickets;
    }
    public void setNooftickets(int nooftickets) {
        this.nooftickets = nooftickets;
    }

}```



But booking id is not incrementing, why?
````

Comment: Very vague question looks like you want to increment the id? The problem is you are initiating ```BookService bs=new BookService(); ``` each time. Make this as a singleton class. and this ensures you always a single instant of BookService to validate. 

And you have do b.setBookingid(++bid);

Answer (score 1):

> Your Book Service Class can be a Singleton class. Define it like the following.

```
public enum BookService {
 INSTANCE;
 private int bid;
 private BookValidator bava;
 public BookService(){
  this.bid=1;
  this.bava =new BookValidator();
 }
 //to make this thread safe
 public synchronized int getTickets(BookDetailsBean b) throws Exception {
    if (bava.IsValidName(b.getName()) && 
              bava.IsValidEmail(b.getEmail()) && 
                   bava.IsValidTicket(b.getNooftickets())){
         b.setBookingid(++bid);
    }else{
         throw new Exception("Invalid booking!");
    }
    return b.getBookingid();
 }

}
```

As you are anyway adding it to the static list further on, there is no need to pick the next id from the size of list.

> Your main class can be like this :

```
    try {
        System.out.println(BookService.INSTANCE.gettickets(bean));
        UserInterfaceBook.Bookinglist.add(bean);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That's not actually threadsafe unless the BookingDetailsBean is immutable.